# Linux shell simulation: stuck on multiple pipes

Tags: c++, linux, fork, pipe

I know similar questions have already been asked but none of the replies helped me. I am trying to implement a miniature Linux shell and am stuck on multiple pipes. Commands with a single pipe (e.g. `ls | wc`) work, but if I add a second pipe, nothing is shown on the console. Here is my code.

```
void ExecuteCommand(NODE *cHead,NODE *oHead)
{
    int fd[10][2];  // file descriptors' array
    int nfdCnt = 0 ;    // file descriptors counter
    string strCmd;      // command
    string strOp = "";  // operator
    int nOpCnt = 0 ;    // operator count

    while(1)
    {
        if (cHead != NULL)  // cHead is head pointer to the linked list of commands.
        {
            strCmd =  GetCmdOROperator(&cHead); // get command
        }
        if (oHead == NULL)  // oHead is head pointer to the linked list of operators.
        {
            strOp = "";
        }
        else
        {
            strOp = GetCmdOROperator(&oHead);   // get operator
        }

        if (strOp.empty())  // no operator exists. single or last command in the chain.
        {
            // Fork the child process
            pid_t child_id = fork();

            if(child_id == 0)
            {
                // Execute the command

                if (nOpCnt) // if we previously encountered any operator
                {
                    close(fd[nfdCnt-1][FD_WRITE]);
                    dup2(fd[nfdCnt-1][FD_READ], FD_READ);   // read from pipe updated by previous command
                }

                // call execvp()

                exit(-1);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0 ; i < nfdCnt; i++)
                {
                    close(fd[nfdCnt][0]);
                    close(fd[nfdCnt][1]);
                }
                wait(NULL);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (strOp == "|")
        {
            nOpCnt++ ;

            if (pipe (fd[nfdCnt]) < 0)
            {
                printf("\npipe error");
                return ;
            }

            pid_t child_id = fork();
            if (child_id == 0)
            {
                close(fd[nfdCnt][FD_READ]); // we dont need this
                dup2(fd[nfdCnt][FD_WRITE], FD_WRITE);

                if(nOpCnt > 1) // if we have already encountered a pipe before
                {
                    dup2(fd[nfdCnt-1][FD_READ],FD_READ);
                    close(fd[nfdCnt-1][FD_WRITE]);
                }

                // call execvp()
                exit (-1);
            }
            else
            {
                nfdCnt++;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3` you exec cmd2 before you've set up the pipe between cmd2 and cmd3 (assuming the `call execvp()` before `exit(-1)` will be uncommented).

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for your response but I am setting up pipe before hand for each piped command. You could observe that before each fork() in 'if(strOp == '|')' block, I am creating pipe. And yeah, those execvp() calls are not commented. In my actual code, I tokenize and convert 'strCmd' to char* for execvp(), so I just put a comment here to save some space.

Comment: You are not closing file descriptors.  After `dup2( a, b )`, you should close `a`.  When file descriptors get left open, things tend to hang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked too closely at your code, but it looks like you are leaving file descriptors open, in which case processes will block on a read since someone has the write side open even though you think you've closed it.  Try adding a close after each dup2:

```
 dup2( fd[ nfdCnt - 1 ][ FD_READ ], FD_READ );
 close( fd[ nfdCnt - 1 ][ FD_READ ])
```

(Also, add some error checking.  `dup2`, `fork`, `close`, etc. can all fail.  It is sometimes convenient to skip error checking when posting questions to a forum, but make sure that you don't omit it in actual code.)

Comment: @ William Pursell: I think I was not closing the pipes and that was the problem. Now its working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you close fd[0] immediately after dup2(fd[0],0) or do you have to do your stuff with fd[0] open?

Comment: @mehran Close it immediately after the dup2.  There's no reason to keep it open.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
 if (strOp == "|")
```

doesn't work in C; use `strcmp` to compare strings. Or maybe you mistagged your question C instead of C++? What language compiler do you use?

Comment: The `string` type declaration suggests it's C++.

Comment: @Jens I am using c++ compiler, so I think this is not the cause. but thanks for pointing it out. I have modified the tag.